# Add path with aux jars for Hive client

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop2, hortonworks-data-platform

I did have HDP 2.6.1.0-129

I have external Jar example.jar for serialized flume data file.

I did add new parametr in section Custom hive-site

```
name = hive.aux.jars.path
value hdfs:///user/libs/
```

Did save new configuration and did restart hadoop componens and in more time restart all hadoop cluster.

After in Hive client I did try to run select

```
select * from example_serealized_table
```

and hive did return error

```
FAILED: RuntimeException MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.my.bigtable.example.model.gen.TSerializedRecord not found)
```

How solve this problem?

p.s.

If did try add in current session,

```
add jar hdfs:///user/libs/example-spark-SerializedRecord.jar;
```

Did try to put *.jar to local folder.
Problem same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not say that library write my my colleague did write a library.
It did turn out that it redefines the variables that affect the level of logging the field.
After excluding overridden variables in the library, the problem of reproducing did stopp.